# How to prove the this sobolev-like inequality presented in the paper “sobolev inequalities in disguise”

Tags: inequalities, interpolation

[click to see the picture of one related 
page from the paper](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I1iGJ.png)

[this is the link of the whole paper](https://www.math.univ-toulouse.fr/~ledoux/BCLS.pdf)

**What I cannot really clearly understands is the content bellow:**
[the shortcut of the inequality](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3APwi.jpg)

If you don’t want to see the pictures,here is the main description:
Let 
$$N_{a,b}^{\rho}(f)=\left(\sum\limits_{k \in \mathbb{Z}}\rho^{bk}\mu(f \ge \rho^k)^{b/a}\right)^{1/b},\rho > 1,a,b >0,\\f \ \text{is  measurable}, \mu \ \text{is the Lebesgue measure}.$$
Then there is the inequality 
$$
N_{r,u}^{\rho}(f) \leq \left( N_{s,v}^{\rho}(f) \right)^{\nu}\left(N_{t,w}^{\rho}(f) \right)^{1-\nu},\\
\text{with}\  \frac{1}{r}=\frac{\nu}{s}+\frac{1-\nu}{t},
\frac{1}{u}=\frac{\nu}{v}+\frac{1-\nu}{w},\nu \in (0,1).
$$

This can be used to show that
$$
||f||_{a,b^{‘}} \leq 2^{\frac{2}{b}}||f||_{a,b},\ for \ \ 0<b\leq b^{‘}\leq \infty
$$
Mark:make sure that you don’t mix the symbol v with $\nu$.

I’ll be sincerely appreciated if anyone can solve the problem.

Comment: I think that it might be better to link directly to the paper - https://www.math.univ-toulouse.fr/~ledoux/BCLS.pdf - rather than including pictures. I have edited the post to include the part from your second screenshot. If needed, you can edit it further to make clear which part is problematic; to include additional context, etc.

Comment: It’s my first time to ask question there,so may not show the problem friendly.Thanks for your advise,I’ve make the problem clear just now.

Comment: I fixed the numerators in the formulae for $\frac1r,\frac1u$, else the inequality was non-homogeneous and obviously wrong, now it is true.

Comment: I did't get the idea?What do you mean for that "I fixed the numerators in the formulae for $1/r,1/u$, else the inequality was non-homogeneous and obviously wrong"?

Comment: it was written $1/r=1/s+(1-\nu)/t$ instead of $1/r=\nu/s+(1-nu)/t$, the same for second formula.

Comment: But the fomulae for 1/r,1/u is right,isn’t it?you Kane just see my solution for the problem.

Comment: Can you get the second result of the norm equality?

Answer (score 1):

Denote $c_k=\mu(f \ge \rho^k)$, actually we do not need anything about these non-negative numbers. Use the Hölder inequality $$\left(\sum a_k\right)^\alpha\left(\sum b_k\right)^\beta\geqslant \left(a_k^{\alpha/(\alpha+\beta)}b_k^{\beta/(\alpha+\beta)}\right)^{\alpha+\beta}$$
for non-negative numbers. In our situation $\alpha=\nu/v$, $\beta=(1-\nu)/u$, $a_k=\rho^{vk}c_k^{v/s}$, $b_k=\rho^{wk}c_k^{w/t}$.

Comment: I've solved the problem under the instruction of my tutor,it was  really a pleasent time and I planned to go back to answer this question by myself.And it's amazing that you've solved the problem in such a short time and even with the almost same method! I'm really thankful for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Denote $h_k(r)=\rho^k \mu(f \geq p^k)^{\frac{1}{r}}$,then $h_k(r)=h_k(s)^{\nu}h_k(t)^{(1-\nu)}$,
use Sobolev inequality $\sum\limits_{k}a_kb_k \leq (\sum\limits_{k}a_k^p)^{\frac{1}{p}}(\sum\limits_{k}a_k^p)^{\frac{1}{q}},with \frac{1}{p} + \frac{1}{q}=1,p>1.$

In our situation,we let $p=\frac{v}{u\nu},q=\frac{w}{u(1-\nu)},a_k=h_k(s)^{u\nu},b_k=h_k(t)^{u(1-\nu)}.Then$
\begin{aligned}
N_{r,u}^{\rho}(f)=\left(\sum\limits_{k \in \mathbb{Z}}h_k(r)^u\right)^{\frac{1}{u}} &= \left(\sum\limits_{k \in \mathbb{Z}}h_k(s)^{u\nu}\cdot h_k(t)^{u(1-\nu)}\right)^{\frac{1}{u}}\\
&\leq \left[\left(\sum h_k(s)^v \right)^{\frac{u\nu}{v}}\left(\sum h_k(t)^w \right) ^{\frac{u(1-\nu)}{w}}\right]^{\frac{1}{u}}\\
&=\left(N_{s,v}^{\rho}(f) \right)^{\nu}\left(N_{t,w}^{\rho}(f) \right)^{1-\nu} \#.
\end{aligned} 
$\int_Ef^{r\cdot \alpha/(\alpha - 1)}d\mu \le (CW_n(f^{\alpha/(\alpha - 1)})^{\vartheta}||f^{\alpha/(\alpha - 1)}||_s \le C^{r\vartheta}||f||_1 $

\begin{aligned}
\int_E \sum_{j=1}^{N}\frac{(b|f|^{\alpha/(1-\alpha)})^j}{j!} &= \sum_{j=1}^{N} \frac{b^j}{j!}\int_E|f|^{j\cdot \frac{\alpha}{\alpha - 1}}d\mu \le \sum_{j=1}^{N}\frac{b^j}{j!}C^{j\vartheta(j)}||f||_1
\end{aligned} 
 &\le